# unable to use INSERT with returning native query from Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am using native SQL query in Spring Data JPA repository and want to return auto generated id after upsert.
Look like a similar snippet below:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO entity (name, age) VALUES(?1,?2) " +
                       "ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET name=?1,age=?2 " +
                       "RETURNING id", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer upsert(String name, int age); 
}
```

After execution I get the next PSQLException:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:141)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
```

So, the problem is here:

```
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement:

public int executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
   executeWithFlags(QueryExecutor.QUERY_NO_RESULTS);

   ResultWrapper iter = result;
   while (iter != null) {
     if (iter.getResultSet() != null) {
        throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("A result was returned when none was expected."),
        PSQLState.TOO_MANY_RESULTS);

     }
   iter = iter.getNext();
  }

return getUpdateCount();
}
```

The problem would be solved if I could set another QueryExecutor flags or call update statement with `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. But now it seems there is no way specify it from Spring Data Repository. I know I can do what I want from stored procedure but it is not so handy as some parameter in annotation.

So, what do you think? Should it be considered as a bug in Spring Data & Postgres JDBC?

UPD:
Opened Jira issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1389